# Filter out entries with empty Grid

Tags: search, grid, ee4, ee5

What am I doing wrong?
What I try to reach is getting all entries that DO contain a grid-row.
video is name of grid field, fragment is name of the column.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" dynamic="no" search:video:fragment="not IS_EMTPY"}

    [here-content]

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <?php $i = 1;?>
        {exp:channel:entries channel="nieuws" dynamic="no" limit="100"}
        {video limit="1"}
        <?php if($i < 9):?>
            <article class="video-item col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div>
                    {video:fragment}
                    <a href="{page_uri}">
                        <h3>{title}</h3>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </article>
            <?php if($i == 4):?><div class='clearfix'></div><?php endif;?>

            <?php $i++;?>
        <?php endif; ?> 
        {/video}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the grid fields aren't searchable with search=
however you can search in the grid tag itself

```
{video search:fragment="not IS_EMPTY"}
    fields
{/video}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to search into Grid then first you should enable all fields which you want to search, by `Include in search?` parameter from the Grid fieldtype. After that you should add `search:column_name=` with your grid field_name into your code.

In your case you should try with below code.

```
{video search:column_name="not IS_EMPTY"}
    {!-- your code --}
{/video}
```

I hope this will works for you.

Comment: Thanks Jelle and Harsh for the suggested solution. I created a work-around with a custom counter to limit to max 4 entries. This is because I only want to show the latest 4 video's of entries that do contain a video. So if i limit to 4 entries... this won't give the result. Because not every entry contains a video. Will send code when finished.